# the aura has been exposed?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was going through an article. The article is on forcing a leader out of the position of president of some election party. In the post, one of speaker said:
**The aura of the leader has been  exposed now.**

What I didn't understand is what someone means when (s)he says: "the aura of leader has been exposed now"?

The link to the [post](http://indianexpress.com/article/india/dalit-politics-uttar-pradesh-17-dalit-obc-muslim-groups-meet-to-plan-mayawati-bsp-ouster-bahujan-4785289/).

Comment: Can you give us more context for the sentence? What was the article, what was it about? What do you already understand about the sentences around this one? A link to the article would also be great. That will help folks give you a more accurate answer.

Comment: @1006a I have edited the question. Please comment if there is further need for editing my question.

Comment: the edit makes it more difficult to comprehend as the context is lost.

Answer (score 1):

What Kureel wants to say is that the source of Mayawati's erstwhile clout is now in the open.

The implication is that a lot of senior leaders with her, were essentially supporters of her mentor Kansi Ram, but since his demise no longer are under any organised political party.

Having said that, the question is not necessarily in the purview of this site as it is more concerned with politics of Uttar Pradesh than with the language itself.